# Nested vs non-nested queries against nested fields in elasticsearch with include_in_parent enabled

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, elasticsearch-5

I am using elasticsearch 5.1.1.
I have index with following part of the mapping :

```
{
"properties": {
    "machine": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "networkInterface": {
                "type": "nested",
                "include_in_parent": true,
                "macAddress": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I am trying to find machines which have at least one interface with non-null macAddress.
Tried following type of queries :

Non-nested query :

```
    {
    "bool": {
        "must_not": [
            {
                "bool": {
                    "must_not": [
                        {
                            "exists": {
                                "field": "networkInterface.macAddress",
                                "boost": 1
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "disable_coord": false,
                    "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                    "boost": 1
                }
            }
        ],
        "disable_coord": false,
        "adjust_pure_negative": true,
        "boost": 1
    }
}
```

Nested query :

```
    {
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "must_not":[
        {
          "nested":{
            "query":{
              "bool":{
                "must_not":[
                  {
                    "exists":{
                      "field":"networkInterface.macAddress",
                      "boost":1
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "disable_coord":false,
                "adjust_pure_negative":true,
                "boost":1
              }
            },
            "path":"networkInterface",
            "ignore_unmapped":false,
            "score_mode":"none",
            "boost":1
          }
        }
      ],
      "disable_coord":false,
      "adjust_pure_negative":true,
      "boost":1
    }
  }
}
```

I have a machine document with 3 network interfaces as follows :

```
[
  {
    "name":"x",
    "macAddress":"<mac-add1>"
  },
  {
    "name":"y",
    "macAddress":null
  },
  {
    "name":"z",
    "macAddress":"<mac-addr2>"
  }
]
```

With the first query it returns the machine. But with the second one, it does not.

Is it because of include_in_parent enabled?
Or am I not understanding how nested and non-nested queries against nested field work?
Or is the nested query incorrect?

Comment: Can someone please check this question?